# Print lines between two patterns, a few lines before the first pattern and a few lines after the last pattern

Tags: python

I have a large and complex file that I want to parse, so I'm going to use a simpler example. Suppose a file content like:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
line13
line14
line15
```

I want to print lines between two patterns (e.g. line6 and line9) with, for example, two lines before the first pattern and two lines after the last pattern, so the output would be like:

```
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
```

The code I have so far only prints the lines between both patterns:

```
first_pattern = "line6"
last_pattern = "line9"

with open(file, "r") as f:
    inside_region = False
    for line in f:
        if first_pattern in line:
            inside_region = True
        if inside_region:
            print(line)  # Printing the lines between two patterns
        if last_pattern in line:
            inside_region = False
            break
```

How could I also print a few lines before the first pattern and a few after the last pattern? I should be able to change the number of those extra lines, with something like `lines_before_after = 2` or `lines_before_after = 10`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple with `readlines()` and the `list.index()` methods:

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    text = f.readlines() #overlapping chunks if excessively large file
buffer = 2
start_index = text.index('line6')
end_index = text.index('line9')
print('\n'.join(text[start_index-buffer:end_index+buffer+1]))
```

If the file is too large to hold in memory, you could look into chunking the data with overlaps.

**Edit**
As per trincot's comment, the above only works if the pattern matches the entire line. However, the same idea can be applied using a for loop:

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    text = f.readlines() #overlapping chunks if excessively large file
buffer = 2
start_index = None
end_index = None
for line in text:
    if start_pattern in line:
        start_index = text.index(line)
    elif end_pattern in line:
        end_index = text.index(line)
    if start pattern and end pattern:
        print('\n'.join(text[start_index-buffer:end_index+buffer+1]))
        break #end loop if both start and end indices found
```

Each of these solutions assume only one line will match for each of the patterns, but can be adapted otherwise.

Comment: `index` does not have the same behaviour is the asker's `in` operator.

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this by modifying your code to keep track of the lines before and after the patterns.

```py
first_pattern = "line6"
last_pattern = "line9"
lines_before_after = 2  # You can change this to control the number of lines before and after

with open(file, "r") as f:
    lines_buffer = []
    for line in f:
        lines_buffer.append(line)
        if len(lines_buffer) > lines_before_after * 2:
            lines_buffer.pop(0)
        
        if last_pattern in line:
            break
        
        if first_pattern in line:
            for buffered_line in lines_buffer[:-lines_before_after]:
                print(buffered_line, end='')
            print(line, end='')
            for buffered_line in lines_buffer[-lines_before_after:]:
                print(buffered_line, end='')
```

Comment: Evidently you didn't test this code.